# Reading tab file in C# and appending to a string

Tags: c#

I am reading a tab-delimited file in C#. I am passing each value to an INSERT statement by using StringBuilder.

My code is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO `interactions` (`id`, `id_interaction`) VALUES ");

var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Edges.txt").Take(50).ToArray().Distinct();
List<string> rows = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in lines)
{
    string[] values = item.Split("\t");

    rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}', '{1}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(values[0]), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(values[1])));

    var sep = string.Join(",", rows);

    sCommand.Append(sep);
}
```

On breakpoint mode, I have sep holding values: `"('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88'),('90', '2339'),('2624', '5371'),('6118', '6774')"` which are good.

But when I append the sep to the sCommand string, the string turns out to be: `INSERT INTO`interactions`(`id`,`id_interaction`) VALUES ('6416', '2318')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88'),('90', '2339')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88'),('90', '2339')...`

Can someone please help me with this ? Why does this `('6416', '2318')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88')` sequence occur?

Comment: Can you share you file with values? Also `sCommand` contains the results added at previous iteration, it can be a reason of this behavior. Also it isn't fully clear, what is `MySqlHelper` doing and why do you need to store the values inside `rows` collection.

Comment: 6416 2318
84665 88
90 2339
2624 5371
6118 6774
375 23163
377 23647
377 27236
54464 226
351 10513
333 1600
10370 7020
2033 7020
338 4547
409 5900
1436 2885
7916 2885
27257 4677
6521 22950
602 580
153 10755
672 466
672 4436
672 580
672 2956
421 1013
5092 775
5664 823
825 7273
3708 767

Comment: At every iteration you are adding two first values to `rows` list, ad than join it into the string and append. A every iteration you'll get a values from previous one. It isn't fully clear, what are you asking about

Comment: Side Note: escaping sql is tricky. I don't know what your MySqlHelper does but I recommend you use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

sCommand.Append(sep) is being called for each iteration of the `foreach` loop.

Your string is likely being correctly appended to the end, and the snippet you showed (`VALUES ('6416', '2318')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88'),('90', '2339')('6416', '2318'),('84665', '88'),('90', '2339')...`) may be the result of appending done in earlier iterations of the `foreach` loop.

It might be worth inspecting your Edges.txt file?

Edit: Anu has the correct explanation - see Anu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the behavior, it would be worth examining the values of rows,sep, and sCommand in each iteration.

Iteration 1

[image]

Iteration 2
[image]

Iteration 3
[image]

Iteration 4
[image]

As you can observe, in each iteration, you are adding an `string` to the List.However, when you append to `sCommand`, you are joining the entire list and appending. This would mean, you are appending `strings`, which are already part of the sCommand repeatedly with each iteration.

To fix it, you would need to make following moving following lines out of the loop.

```
var sep = string.Join(",", rows);
sCommand.Append(sep);
```

What this does is that you would first create the complete collection within the loop and then, only at the end, appends the values to the `StringBuilder`.
Code would look like

```
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    string[] values = item.Split('\t');
    rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}', '{1}')", values[0], values[1]));
}

var sep = string.Join(",", rows);
sCommand.Append(sep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the last two lines out of the foreach loop.

rows.Add is in your foreach loop, this adds as many rows as there are lines. So this is the full set you need.

Your append is in the foreach so it is appending the rows it has at that moment:

e.g. I have the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, in the foreach I add it as rows, the first time I will have 1, this is appended, my string contains "1".

The second time around we will have 1 & 2, this is appended. my string contains now 1,1,2 (1 from last time and 1,2 now.

the third time the rows have 1,2 & 3. the string is 1,1,2,1,2,3

The var sep is adding in

Answer (score 0):

I created a little class for the values in the file. I separated reading the file from the database code; just returning a list to the database code.

```
    class Values
    {
        public string Val1 { get; set; }
        public string Val2 { get; set; }

        public Values(string v1,string v2)
        {
            Val1 = v1;
            Val2 = v2;
        }
    }

    private void InsertValues()
    {
        List<Values> lst = ReadFile();
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `interactions` (`id`, `id_interaction`) VALUES (@id, @idInteraction);", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idInteraction", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cn.Open();
            foreach (Values v in lst)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = v.Val1;
                cmd.Parameters["@idInteraction"].Value = v.Val2;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Values> ReadFile()
    {
        List<Values> lst = new List<Values>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Edges.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] vals = line.Split(',');
            Values v = new Values(vals[0].Trim(), vals[1].Trim());
            lst.Add(v);
        }
        return lst;
    }
```